# Supervised learning with uncertain data?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Is there an existing methodology for applying a supervised learning model to a uncertain dataset? For example, say we have a dataset with classes A and B:

```
+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
| FeatureA | FeatureB | Label | Certainty |
+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|        2 |        3 | A     | 50%       |
|        3 |        1 | B     | 80%       |
|        1 |        1 | A     | 100%      |
+----------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

How could we train a machine learning model on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a numerical quality you ascribe to your data, I think this "certainty" could surely be used as a weight. Higher "certainty" scores increase the weight a datum has on the decision function, which makes sense.

Many supervised learning algorithms support weights, so you just have to find a weighted version of the one you intend to use.

Comment: (+1) And since essentially the weights will tend to act as "replicates" of points, probably **any** algorithm could be kludged into a weighted version that way, e.g. in the OP example, pass in [5,8,10] copies of the 3 points, reflecting their certainties of [50,80,100]%. (This should never be truly needed, as if it could be done in principle, there should be a corresponding weighted version of the algorithm.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having labels A or B, you could replace them with continuous values of the certainty -- for example, $1$ corresponds to something you're sure is $A$, $0$ corresponds to something you're sure is $B$ and $0.6$ corresponds to something you're 40% sure is $A$. Then, have a model that instead of predicting class $A$ or $B$ outputs a score between $0$ and $1$ based on how much you think its one or the other (and threshold this score based on if its > or < 1/2). This turns your classification problem into a regression problem (which you threshold to get back to a classifier).

For example, you could fit a linear model to $\log \frac{p(A|x)}{p(B|x)} = \log \frac{p(A|x)}{1-P(A|x)} $ as $ \beta_0 + \beta_1^T x $ (where $p(A|x)$ is the certainty above). Then, when you want to test some data, plug it into the model, and output label $A$ if $ \beta_0 + \beta_1^T x >0 $ and $B$ otherwise.

Comment: So if you had a multi-class classification problem, you could set your targets as vectors with length equal to the number of classes?

Comment: Number of classes -1, assuming the certainties sum to 100%; the example is similar to logistic regression. A lot of classifiers produce scores (e.g. estimates of the p(class | data) under some model). All this answer proposes is that instead of predicting the classes directly, view the certainties as scores, and predict them instead. Then, do something with the scores.